# What frameworks are Mint.com using for their pie and bar charts?

Tags: charts, pie-chart

Does anyone know what frameworks they are using to create these or are they doing all of these in house?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest contacting them and asking who their web developer is.  Phone is probably going to be more productive than email.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the answer on Quora from the guy who created them:

http://www.quora.com/Jason-Putorti/What-charting-library-framework-did-you-use-at-Mint-com

> I actually wrote the first version of
>   the trends tab in Flex
>   (http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/)
>   using the Flex Charting Components
>   (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3...).
>   Flex is very easy to learn and develop
>   in and I feel is much easier to
>   maintain than a
>   Flash/ActionScript-only solution

Answer (score 1):

They're all done in Flash

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely done with the Flex framework for AS3, however there are some Javascript/HTML5 API's starting to show up in this arena that could trump the Flex ones soon.